# AWS Create New Application Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, package.json

I am new to AWS. I am exploring hosting my rest server on AWS but have not been able to solve the following problem:

> Failed to find package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Verify package.json is valid or place code in a file named server.js or app.js.

There were suggestions that I should zip only the files and sub-dir but not the root folder.
I tried the recommendation suggested to zip just the files and sub-folders but it still doesn't work.
The following are the files I zip:

```
bin
models
node_modules
public
routes
views
app.js
authenticate.js
ca.crt
ca.key
config.js
db.json
ia.crt
ia.csr
ia.key
ia.p12
package.json
```

The following are the content of my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "rest-server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.0",
    "mongoose-currency": "^0.2.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

I am using the Elastic Beanstalk Dashboard not the eb command line method.

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution from AWS developer forum regarding about the error in NodeJS deploy in elasticbeanstalk.It might due to the package.json was not zip in the correct location.

Node.js deploy fail in Elasticbeanstalk
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=130140&tstart=0

You may try to download the sample application from AWS website and follow the folder structure from there:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/tutorials.html